# What is a object in java and what does it do

Tags: java, class, object

I have been banging my head for a while now, understanding java language. I have been familiar with classes but i always get confused with object? I know the question sounds very stupid but I am still not able to figure out what a java object do and why do we need it. How different is it from a plain variable. How to call it. How can I use a java object defined in one class into another? These questions are mocking my head for a while now.
Could someone explain object in simple sentences? 
Any help with some simple example would be very much helpful.

Comment: Class is blueprint. Object is the concrete thing made from the blueprint. Variable is like a name tag that let you refer to the object.

Comment: Without knowing object ho do you get familiar with classes???

Comment: We represents class and its functionality through an object. lets take a simple example ` public class SampleObj` `{` public void add(int a, int b) { System.out.println(a+"+ "+b+" = "+a+b); } public static void main(String[] args) { SampleObj obj=new SampleObj(); // creating object of class obj.add(1,2);// calling a method (functionality ) using object }}`

Comment: I cannot see why this was closed as it was a valid question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class defines the data and behavior that all the instances (objects) of this class will have. For example, the class Dog has a name and color fields, and a `bark()` method. Now if you want to make an application with three dogs, you will create three instances of the Dog class:

```
Dog blacky = new Dog("Blacky", "black");
Dog whity = new Dog("Whity", "white");
Dog rooky = new Dog("Rooky", "red");
```

Once you have a dog you can ask it to bark:

```
blacky.bark();
```

You could also imagine a House class, containing dogs:

```
public class House {
    private Set<Dog> dogsInTheHouse = new HashSet<Dog>();

    public void addDog(Dog dog) {
        this.dogsInTheHouse.add(dog);
    }

    public void someOneIsAtTheDoor() {
        for (Dog dog : dogsInTheHouse) {
            dog.bark();
        }
    }
}
```

So you could create a house:

```
House myHouse = new House();
```

add dogs in the house:

```
myHouse.add(blacky);
myHouse.add(whity);
myHouse.add(rooky);
```

And when you come at the door of the house, all its dogs start barking:

```
myHouse.someOneIsAtTheDoor();
```

So an object can be composed of other objects, and objects can call each others methods to assemble a whole application.

Answer (score 4):

You should find all the information on the Oracle Page: [What Is an Object?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html).

A class can be seen as a blue print, or mould if you will. An object is simply an implementation of that mould, something you can actually work with.

Comment: @Kishorepandey: You are welcome. That being said, such question can't really be answered by just one post. You will need to search online and get your hands dirty with code.